# Is it Possible to view the registered user details in jboss without using browser?

Tags: jboss

If i am creating an user using `addUser.bat` in `jboss`. Is it possible to view the details of the user in `jboss` and where it will be stored and how it will authenticated. Can we edit the user details using `configuration.xml` or without using browser

Answer (score 0):

You will find the user and encrypted password in `mgmt/application-users.properties` and their respective groups/roles in `mgmt-groups.properties` or in `application-roles.properties` present in `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration` for standalone mode and `JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration` for domain mode.

To edit user, run add-user.bat again and pass same user. It will ask if you want to override the user password/roles.

Comment: is it possible to decrypt the data?